# What's the equivalent to Mathematica's Range[] function in C++?

Tags: c++

*Mathematica* has a function called `Range[]` that does the following:

```
Range[0, 10]
Range[-10, 0]
```

Ant it prints:

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
{-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0}
```

Does C++ have such a function?

Comment: Bare C++? No. Third party libraries? Yes.

Comment: With bare C++ I could only make it by declaring a function, right?

Comment: Better yet, follow the answers presented. They are more tested and is generally safer than cleanroom functions or classes.

Comment: `std::iota` works well here.

Comment: @chris Mentioning `std::iota` would make an excellent answer!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, True, but [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152252/is-there-a-compact-equivalent-to-python-range-in-c-stl/13152274#13152274) is very similar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

None in the standard library, but from `boost::range`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::copy(boost::irange(0, 11), 
                std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Output:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Answer (score 7):

Seems easy enough to create one.

```
std::vector<int> range(int from, int to) {
    std::vector<int> result;
    result.reserve(to-from+1);
    for (int i = from; i <= to; ++i) {
        result.push_back(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This wont work for the second case of the question, I'
m sure you know that but I thought maybe other people wouldn't.

Comment: @Ben: Sure it will. What makes you think it won't?

Comment: Woops, i read the second case as [0 -10] You are completely right. My apologies.

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, here is how you can do it with the C++11 standard library and *lambdas*:

```
vector<int> v;
int counter = -3;    // The initial value
generate_n(
    back_inserter(v) // Where to insert
,   10               // how many items
,   [&counter] () -> int { return counter++; });
```

Here is a [link to ideone with a demo](http://ideone.com/qpZSn6).

Answer (score 2):

There is only two libraries that provide **lazy** and **O(1)** memory numeric ranges:

- [Boost irange](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html)  - only integral; no negative step(?); can not be assigned  to other containers.
- [RO numeric_range](http://volnitsky.com/project/ro/#_numeric_range) - needs C++11

With [SCC](http://volnitsky.com/project/scc) (C++ REPL) and RO:

```
scc 'range(0,10)'
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

scc 'range(-10,0)'
{-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0}
```