# Is there in OpenCV operation that is like op1:op2 in Matlab?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I just started use OpenCV and trying to create sequence of numbers , let's say 99,100,...,103. In Matlab I can do that with

```
99:103
```

Does OpenCV have something like this?
And for indexing matrix / vectors.

I feel like

```
cv::Range()
```

the thing that I need but still wasn't able to figure how to use it.

Comment: What do you want to do? For matrix indexing, `cv::Range()` is the right choice, to crate an iterator or a list, it's the wrong choice. Could you describe the use-case you are interested in?

Comment: Daniel, intrested in both. Trying to grasp a concept in OpenCV to connect it with Matlab programming expirience, but here's thing that I'm dealing with now:

I created Range, for ex. cv::Range(99, 103), and now want to use values of such a vector as argument to some function. Let's suppose I want to substract from each value of this vector number 3 and save result.

Comment: To create an array with the values, I would use [`std:itoa`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152252/is-there-a-compact-equivalent-to-python-range-in-c-stl)

Comment: @Daniel - That's a good duplicate.  Have marked it as such.