# range based for used for primitive type

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer

As seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47020276/n-0-1-n-1-in-c#47020276) question, the OP was trying to make following statement iterate over the numbers.

```
for (int n : 10)
    cout << n << endl;
```

Obviously, wrong syntax, because `int` has no `begin()` and `end()` methods. But it should be possible. Based on documentation of [*range-based for loop*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) this is important.

> `for` `(` *range_declaration* `:` *range_expression* `)` *loop_statement*
>
> *range_expression* - any expression that represents a suitable sequence 
>   (either an array or an object for which begin and end member functions or free functions are defined, see below) or a braced-init-list.

And following

> The above syntax produces code equivalent to the following (`__range`, `__begin` and `__end` are for exposition only):
>
> ```
> { // until C++17
>     auto && __range = range_expression ;
>     for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
>         range_declaration = *__begin;
>         loop_statement
>     }
> }
> ```

With clarification of *begin_expr* and *end_expr* are:

> *begin_expr* and *end_expr* are defined as follows:
>
> - If *range_expression* is an expression of array type, then [...]
> - If *range_expression* is an expression of a class type C [...]
> - Otherwise, *begin_expr* is `begin(__range)` and *end_expr* is `end(__range)`, which are found via argument-dependent lookup (non-ADL lookup is not performed).

In our case *range_expression* is `10`, which is not of array type nor of a class type, so last bullet should take effect. So we provide these functions

```
auto begin(int) {
    return boost::counting_iterator<int>(0);
}

auto end(int n) {
    return boost::counting_iterator<int>(n);
}
```

(`boost::counting_iterator` could be easily implemented). And it should work, right? However it fails with

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:17:18: error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope
     for (int t : 10)
                  ^~
main.cpp:17:18: note: suggested alternatives:
main.cpp:5:6: note:   'begin'
 auto begin(int) {
      ^~~~~

In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/vector:66:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/range_access.h:105:37: note:   'std::begin'
   template<typename _Tp> const _Tp* begin(const valarray<_Tp>&);
                                     ^~~~~
```

(and same message for `end`). However, if I change the range-based for loop according to description, I get following, which works.

```
{
    auto && __range = 10;
    for (auto __begin = begin(__range), __end = end(__range); __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
        int t = *__begin;
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b26e1d57ea3c376)

Comment: You're just... asking the same question that you linked to?

Comment: @Barry Not actually, the question I linked is asking how to do that, whereas I am asking why this idea wont't work.

Comment: Does the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47020785/2069064) to that question not answer your question?

Comment: @Barry Well it does, but at the time I've starting writing this question, it was not there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key phrase is:

> which are found via argument-dependent lookup (non-ADL lookup is not performed)

`int` has no namespace. No, not even the *global* namespace. As such, lookup based on the namespace finds nothing.

To be more specific to the specification, [basic.lookup.argdep]/2.1 says:

> If T is a fundamental type, its associated sets of namespaces and classes are both empty.

And since there are no associated namespaces or classes, ADL doesn't work.

This would be better handled by a user-defined literal that returns a counting range. So you would type `10_rng`, and that would yield a counting range.

Comment: Uh, was hoping for something little more complex given the effort I put into a research :-). Thanks though.

Comment: @Zereges: The ADL-only lookup rule for range-based for is precisely the reason why rule #1 in range-based for exists. That is, why there's special wording specifically for ranges over arrays. After all, `std::begin/end` are overloaded for arrays, so why have wording for `for` with arrays? Because rule #3 would not be able to find them, since it's ADL-only.