# C++ How to insert a consecutive inter range into std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++17

Say I want all numbers from 23 to 57 be in a `vector`. I can do this:

```
vector<int> result;
for (int i = 23; i <= 57; ++i)
{
    result.push_back(i);
}
```

But this is a 5 line solution for a simple job. Can't I do that more elegantly? The best syntax would be `vector<int> result{23 .. 57};` for example or such a trivial one line code. Any options with C++17?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) (since C++11).

> Fills the range [first, last) with sequentially increasing values, starting with `value` and repetitively evaluating `++value`.
>
> The function is named after the integer function ⍳ from the programming language APL.

e.g.

```
std::vector<int> result(57 - 23 + 1);
std::iota(result.begin(), result.end(), 23);
```

Comment: And what `iota` means? Any acronym?

Comment: @Narek check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244879/what-does-iota-of-stdiota-stand-for

Answer (score 6):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), it would be:

```
const std::vector<int> result = ranges::view::ints(23, 58); // upper bound is exclusive
```

With C++20, [`std::ranges::iota_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view):

```
const auto result1 = std::ranges::views::iota(23, 58); // upper bound is exclusive
const auto result2 = std::ranges::iota_view(23, 58); // upper bound is exclusive
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile with gcc-10. Do you know current C++20 equivalent?

Comment: @PaulJurczak: C++20 iota view added.

Comment: I'm getting `error: conversion from ‘std::ranges::iota_view<int, int>’ to non-scalar type ‘const std::vector<int>’ requested` with gcc 10.0.1

Comment: @PaulJurczak: Indeed, C++20 ranges seems not convertible directly to `std::vector`, `std::vector<int> v{range.begin(), range.end()};` should to the job.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another possibility is to use `boost::counting_iterator`[1]. This also has the advantage of working with C++98, should you be unfortunate enough to be stuck with it.

```
#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>
```

…

```
result.insert(result.end(), boost::counting_iterator<int>(23), boost::counting_iterator<int>(58));
```

or, even simpler:

```
vector<int> result(boost::counting_iterator<int>(23), boost::counting_iterator<int>(58));
```

Note that, as a normal half-open range is expected in either case, you'll have to use `lastNum+1`, and you will not be able to insert `numeric_limits<int>::max()` (aka `INT_MAX`) for this reason.

[1] https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html